# Android In app billing confirmation dialog isn't appearing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-account

I've implemented IAB using https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3 and test it on alpha test channel.
When start to test it, payment works well, but after certain number of payment, confirm dialog isn't appearing.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eo0182R2nO8
Please help me how to show the confirmation dialog for every purchase.

Comment: Have you found the solution?